# How to develop a Maya Viewport Extension in C++(MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, viewport, maya

I need to develop a Maya Viewport Extension in C++ with(MFC)，also need to control view style(such as top view, left view etc.).Can I use Maya SDK to archive this and how to make it?Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not perfectly sure what you mean by "Viewport Extension".
I guess you're trying to write a Maya Plug-In that features your own type of viewport,
 which is commonly called "Model View".

MCF does not have anything to do with this.
You use Maya MEL/Python commands to create Maya windows, panels and other UI-elements.
*(if there is a hack to make Maya work with windows you've created yourself, I don't know it)*.

You can develop custom viewports in Maya by creating two classes:
A viewport or model view, and a "**model editor command**".

### Model View

One is your viewport class, let's call it "MyViewport".
It has to inherit "MPx3dModelView".
Normally you will associate a camera with the viewport. This let's you control from where you see the scene. You can have multiple cameras connected to your viewport (multi-pass display, for example stereo 3D), or none at all (but then you must set all rendering parameters by yourself, which can be tedious).

The (callback) functions you inherit from that class allow you to set up the details for your viewport.

See the Maya documentation on MPx3dModelView to see how to use it.
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/API/class_m_px3d_model_view.html

### Model Editor Command

The other class you'll need is a viewport command.
That is the thing that get's called when someone tries to create your viewport.
It has to inherit "MPxModelEditorCommand".
It's most important feature is that it can create an instance of your Model Editor class.

See the Maya documentation on MPxModelEditorCommand on how to use it:
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_px_model_editor_command.html

### Registering the viewport command with the Maya plug-in

In order to be able to create your viewport, you must register your Model Editor Command with the plugin.
In your initializePlugin function (the one you export with the plugin)

```
MStatus initializePlugin( MObject obj )

    {
        MFnPlugin plugin( obj, PLUGIN_COMPANY, "1.0", "Any");
        plugin.registerModelEditorCommand(MyModelViewCmd::commandName, MyModelViewCmd::creator, MyModelViewCmd::createModelView);
    }
```

### Writing a script that creates your viewport

Finally, you use MEL or Python scripting in Maya to create your user interface.
In the most simple set-up, you simply create a window and then call your model editor command to create you custom viewport in this window.

```
    window MyWindow;
    paneLayout MyWindowPane;
    MyModelView MyModelView1;
```

Comment: Actually,I need to write a third party App to render Maya's Model.The App acts as extra view port for users to use full screen to edit a model and check for errors.The App is built in C++.Any tip will be appreciate.

Comment: Please update your original question, so it can be re-opened. Answering in these tiny comments doesn't help other people with similar questions.
Also: please be more precise. What do you mean by "third party App"?